# Run node.js application as static files on server without node

Tags: node.js, express

We want to put up a node application on a Linux CentOS 6 server where there is no possibility of installing Node.

So if I've understood correctly, the site can't be run with an Express server that serves the files if node isn't installed on the server. My question is, can I run the site if it is compiled and bundled into static files?

In `app.js`, there is a line where the express method "listen" opens a port for the site to run on. I have seen that there is a "static" alternative: `express.static(root, [options])`

Would it work putting up a node site and run it with that static option, without node being installed on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly the answer you are looking for, but I would recommend that instead of trying to run node.js as an static file you [Dockerize](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) your Node.js application. You should be able to then run the Docker application on CentOS.

Comment: Maybe that is a good option.. does it mean that the files will be on a Docker server then? And my server just fetches eveything from Docker in some way?

Comment: No, Docker is just a container. Kind of like a Virtual Machine. So all the files and the node.js dependencies are in the docker image, but everything runs and is inside your CentOS server

Comment: So I don't need no Docker hub or repo? I thought I needed both container and hub and that the web server would run on Docker with nginx.

Comment: You do need to upload your Docker image to your server, for which you have multiple options:
1. You can use a Docker image repo such as Docker hub
2. You can build it directly on the server, using as a base image the node one from Docker hub.
3. You can upload it though scp or FTP.

The web server does need apache or nginx just as with any other exposed web application.